# Interactive bar chart domain issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create an interactive bar chart of the top Forbes 100 companies, with buttons to change between sales and profit.

The first issue I'm having is with the domain:

```
x.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d[xValue])])
```

Error says "data not defined"

but I defined it here:

```
d3.csv("data/data_clean.csv").then(data => {
    data.forEach(d => {
    d.sales_usd_billion = Number(d.sales_usd_billion)
    d.profit_usd_billion = Number(d.profit_usd_billion)
})
```

data snapshot:

```
rank,company,country,sales_usd_billion,sales_unit,profit_usd_billion,profit_unit,assets_usd_billion,market_usd_billion,sales_usd,profit_usd,assets_usd
1,Berkshire Hathaway,United States,276.09,B,89.8,B,958.78,741.48,276.09,89.8,958.78
2,ICBC,China,208.13,B,54.03,B,5518.51,214.43,208.13,54.03,5518.51
3,Saudi Arabian Oil Company (Saudi Aramco),Saudi Arabia,400.38,B,105.36,B,576.04,2292.08,400.38,105.36,576.04
4,JPMorgan Chase,United States,124.54,B,42.12,B,3954.69,374.45,124.54,42.12,3954.69
5,China Construction Bank,China,202.07,B,46.89,B,4746.95,181.32,202.07,46.89,4746.95
6,Amazon,United States,469.82,B,33.36,B,420.55,1468.4,469.82,33.36,420.55
7,Apple,United States,378.7,B,100.56,B,381.19,2640.32,378.7,100.56,381.19
8,Agricultural Bank of China,China,181.42,B,37.38,B,4561.05,133.38,181.42,37.38,4561.05
9,Bank of America,United States,96.83,B,31,B,3238.22,303.1,96.83,31,3238.22
10,Toyota Motor,Japan,281.75,B,28.15,B,552.46,237.73,281.75,28.15,552.46
11,Alphabet,United States,257.49,B,76.03,B,359.27,1581.72,257.49,76.03,359.27
12,Microsoft,United States,184.9,B,71.19,B,340.39,2054.37,184.9,71.19,340.39
13,Bank of China,China,152.43,B,33.57,B,4192.84,117.83,152.43,33.57,4192.84
14,Samsung Group,South Korea,244.16,B,34.27,B,358.88,367.26,244.16,34.27,358.88
```

FULL CODE:

```
//Forbes companies bar chart 

//set up chart area
const MARGIN = { LEFT: 250, RIGHT: 10, TOP: 50, BOTTOM: 100 }
const WIDTH = 1000 - MARGIN.LEFT - MARGIN.RIGHT
const HEIGHT = 1100 - MARGIN.TOP - MARGIN.BOTTOM



const svg = d3.select("#chart-area").append("svg")
    .attr("width", WIDTH + MARGIN.LEFT + MARGIN.RIGHT)
    .attr("height", HEIGHT + MARGIN.TOP + MARGIN.BOTTOM)

const g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${MARGIN.LEFT}, ${MARGIN.TOP})`)

// X label
g.append("text")
  .attr("class", "x axis-label")
  .attr("x", WIDTH / 2)
  .attr("y", HEIGHT + 50)
  .attr("font-size", "20px")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")

// Y label
const yLabel = g.append("text")
  .attr("class", "y axis-label")
  .attr("x", - (HEIGHT / 2))
  .attr("y", -200)
  .attr("font-size", "20px")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .text("Company")

//scales
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, WIDTH])
const y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([HEIGHT, 0])

//axis generators
const xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom()
const yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft()

//axis groups
const xAxisGroup = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${HEIGHT})`)
const yAxisGroup = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")

//event listeners
$("#var-select").on("change", update)

d3.csv("data/data_clean.csv").then(data => {
    data.forEach(d => {
    d.sales_usd_billion = Number(d.sales_usd_billion)
    d.profit_usd_billion = Number(d.profit_usd_billion)
})


update()
})

function update() {
   
    const t = d3.transition().duration(750)

    //filter based on selections
    const xValue = $("#var-select").val()


    x.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d[xValue])])
    y.domain(data.map(d => d.company))

   
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return  b.rank - a.rank;
  })


//update axes
xAxisCall.scale(x)
xAxis.transition(t).call(xAxisCall)
yAxisCall.scale(y)
yAxis.transition(t).call(yAxisCall)

//***Tooltips */


//*** --- */

rects.enter().append("rect")
.attr("y", d => y(d.company) +3)
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("width", d => x(d[value]))
.attr("height", d => 4)
```

Comment: You need to pass data in your update method and change function definition as function update(data). Its a simple scope problem, I would suggest that try debugging the code and then ask for help here.To learn more about debugging, follow a javascript debugging tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data in your update method and change function definition as function update(data). Its a simple scope problem, I would suggest that try debugging the code and then ask for help here.To learn more about debugging, follow a javascript debugging tutorial